# Is it good practise to give users ability to s3 direct upload using pre-signed URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm writing app that handles large files upload (eg. 10GB). I want to use direct upload to S3 (pre-signed URL) and give that possibility for my web users. My steps are:

1. I'm creating IAM user with only "PUT" permission
2. I'm creating upload policy on the server side (and putting there information about max file size, file content type and policy expiration time (eg. 3 hours)
3. Web user is uploading the file using html form with that policy and pre-signed URL.
4. I'm checking the file headers on a server side after succesfull upload.

Now, I'm wondering about downsides and security issues of this approach. There are any?

Thank you.

Comment: Using pre-signed URLs are also recommended. However, your description doesn't explain how/where you are creating them. You do not need to create a user with only limited permissions. What is needed is the creation of a pre-signed URL on the server-side via credentials that have permission to store the content, with the pre-signed URL passed back to the end-user, typically in a form. Is that what your process is doing?

Comment: Yes of course. In the end user gets html form with  pre-signed url :-)